# ErrorException: Undefined array key &quot;name&quot; in file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vuejs3

I'm busy with a Client Management System which also keeps track of Client Orders. I've set up a CRUD API that handles the back-end database data reading and writing, but when I try to POST the cart data to the database I get the following errors.

> quote Error parsing JSON from response:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', " is not valid JSON
>
> Receiving the following instead of valid JSON:    <!-- ErrorException: Undefined array key
> "name" in file
> C:\Users\mjver\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\client-api\routes\api.php on
> line 238

I've checked the input data into the $data["name"] array on the client-side and I cannot see any errors. I've checked for typos and spelling errors and all the and I'm hoping a few fresh pair of eyes could help out.

My code snippets on the front-end and back-end are as follows:

calling the API call function in api.js:

```
async sendOrder(){
            console.log(this.cart);
            
            const order = await APIController.CreateOrder(this.cart.name, this.cart.qty, this.cart.option, this.cart.price, this.orderNum, this.cart.fee, this.cart.date, this.id);
            if(order){
                store.dispatch('clearCart');
            }
        },
```

The API call in the api.js file:

```
CreateOrder: (name, qty, option, price, orderNo, fee, date, userId) => {
        let responseClone;
        const csrfToken = document.cookie.match(/XSRF-TOKEN=([^;]+)/)[1];
        if(
            name == "" ||
            qty == "" ||
            option == "" ||
            price == "" ||
            orderNo == "" ||
            date == "" ||
            userId == ""
        ) {
            return false;
        } else {

            return fetch(API_BASE + "/orders/create", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ name, qty, option, price, orderNo, fee, date, userId })
            }).then((response) => {
                responseClone = response.clone();
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(data => {
                if(data.success){
                    alert("Order created successfully!")
                    return true;
                } else {
                    throw data.response.error;
                }
            }, (rejectionReason) => {
                console.log('Error parsing JSON from response: ', rejectionReason, responseClone);
                responseClone.text()
                .then((bodyText) => {
                    console.log('Receiving the following instead of valid JSON: ', bodyText);
                });
            }).catch(err => {
                alert(err);
            });
        }
    },
```

The php route in api.php file:

```
Route::post('/orders/create', function(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();

    if(!Orders::where('orderNo', '=', $data['orderNo'])->exists()){
        $order = Orders::create([
            "name" => $data["name"],
            "qty" => $data["qty"],
            "option" => $data["option"],
            "orderNo" => $data["orderNo"],
            "userId" => $data["userId"],
            "price" => $data["price"],
            "fee" => $data["fee"],
            "date" => $data["date"],
        ]);

        if(empty($order->id)){
            return [
                "success" => false,
                "response" => [
                    "error" => "An unusual error has occured"
                ]
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                "success" => true,
                "response" => [
                    "order" => $order
                ]
            ];
        }
    } else {
        return [
            "success" => false,
            "response" => [
                "error" => "The inventory item already exists"
            ]
        ];
    }
});
```

My Orders Models file:

```
class Orders extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'product',
        'qty',
        'option',
        'orderNo',
        'userId',
        'price',
        'fee',
        'date',
    ];

    public function product (){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help with this problem as I've been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: try to add `name` to `$fillable` in the model

Comment: We need to see the wider context of `api.js`. Essentially, where name is passed in, and how that gets there.

Comment: Just check what you got in response, I guess there is some backend error and you received an html page with an error

Comment: Please check my answer below for my solution. And thank you all none the less for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. I console.log(this.cart.name) and found that it was 'undefined'. Upon investigating further I discovered that the reason for that was that the state.cart is an array of objects and not just an object alone.  The reason, of course, being that each separate item in the cart should be it's own object. So my solution was:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= this.cart.length - 1; i++){
                try {
                    const order = await APIController.CreateOrder(this.cart[i].name, this.cart[i].qty, this.cart[i].option, this.cart[i].price, this.orderNum, this.cart[i].fee, this.cart[i].date, this.id);
                    if(order){
                        this.clearCart();
                    }
                } catch (error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
```

Breakdown: since this.cart is an array and not an object I had to use a for loop first to get the index of every item in the cart and then call the function that posts the data to the database.

Answer (score -1):

try this in your php route in api.php file
because in the query you are calling "name" column instead of "product"

```
 Route::post('/orders/create', function(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();

    if(!Orders::where('orderNo', '=', $data['orderNo'])->exists()){
        $order = Orders::create([
            "product" => $data["name"],
            "qty" => $data["qty"],
            "option" => $data["option"],
            "orderNo" => $data["orderNo"],
            "userId" => $data["userId"],
            "price" => $data["price"],
            "fee" => $data["fee"],
            "date" => $data["date"],
        ]);

        if(empty($order->id)){
            return [
                "success" => false,
                "response" => [
                    "error" => "An unusual error has occured"
                ]
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                "success" => true,
                "response" => [
                    "order" => $order
                ]
            ];
        }
    } else {
        return [
            "success" => false,
            "response" => [
                "error" => "The inventory item already exists"
            ]
        ];
    }
});
```

Comment: Why "try this"?  Code-only answers are low-value on Stack Overflow because they miss an excellent opportunity to educate and empower the asker and thousands of future readers.  Please never post code-only answers.  Please always explain your snippets.  You can [edit] your answer at any time.